# Messing with cell phone during D&D sessions

Tags: system-agnostic, problem-players

There are lots of questions on this site about players using their phones (the phone being a symbol for *not keeping their eyes on the game* -- it could be a magazine, a tv, or the bird feeder at the window -- any distraction, basically).  However, they've all come with the caveat that use of the phone **diverts one's attention from the game, thus slowing it down**.

I find myself in a different situation.  I simultaneously use my phone *and* am arguably the most attentive player at the table in most cases.  During combat, I'm regularly the person who already has his turn planned out.  If another person doesn't realize it's *their* turn, I immediately notice it, and, if the pregnant pause goes on too long, I'm the stickler notifying them of that fact.

I've never been called out on my phone use (probably because it's so obvious that I'm engaged when it comes time for me to do something), but **as players and GMs, do you consider phone use during game play to be "bad", even if it does not impact the flow of the game?**

Here are some additional details into why I use the phone:

1. There is inherent downtime in the game.  In combat, when it's not my turn, I'm *waiting* for it to become my turn.  Out of combat is less of an issue in general for me -- I don't play in role-play heavy groups, so there aren't any real immersion concerns in that respect.  So out of combat, my eyes and hands are never required, so they can busy themselves on my phone without any impact on the session.
2. I have busy fingers.  When I'm concentrating, I enjoy having things to do with my hands.  I often do origami (or it's more primitive cousin, folding paper into a grid pattern until it disintegrates), or, obviously, play games on my phone, when I'm doing something that doesn't require my eyes/hands.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.se! I'd like to try to understand your question a bit better. What is the issue you are trying to get advice on here? You say that your group doesn't seem to have an issue with your phone use and that you don't either and are able to stay attentive. It seems to me then that there isn't a problem right? Or am I missing something? In short: what issue are you trying to solve? What kind of answers do you want?

Comment: I think this is a valid modern TTRPG concern that, unfortunately, is heavily opinion based and varies as a norm from table to table. You may have better luck with getting feedback at a discussion forum, as I don't think we can arrive at an objectively correct answer.  We have [a curated list here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/22566)

Comment: *do you consider phone use during game play to be "bad"* — you explicitly ask for a list of opinions, which is off topic here, unfortunately.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Fundamentally, I'm asking if my behavior is something someone might come to this site learn how to get me to stop doing it.  Most related questions cite it having some material impact on the game (i.e., slowing it down, breaking immersion, etc).  Absent those material impacts, what would this community recommend -- that the offended player live with my behavior, or that the offended player reach out to me and try to "resolve" issues that might underlie my phone use.

Comment: @enkryptor I was concerned about that.  Do you think the clarification I gave Rubksmoose above would change the opinion-based nature if I integrated it into the question?

Comment: The clarification doesn't really help, because the material impacts you can't address for us (and which we can't address objectively) depend on how the offended players feel. We can't offer much insight into what these other people feel, or why, and therefore can't offer much about what would be the best course of action. Plus "phone use" isn't well defined-- if you're on D&D Beyond looking up rules, that's totally different from looking at an endless scroll of memes. But one DM might not care at all either way, while another might kick you from the table for it. There is no general answer.

Comment: @Upper_Case Fair enough.  I'll try to think of a way to reframe the question, but as it's current state is the culmination of a bit of thought, I do not have high hope for it.  *checks script*  Wait, it says here I'm supposed to make a derogatory remark about how unwelcoming this place is, threaten to leave forever, and delete my question?  Darn -- I really screwed the pooch on this one, folks!  I'll do better the next time my question is deemed to be unfit for the site!

Comment: @bvoyelr Hah! Well you can always try asking on [Meta] with some more details on what your goals are here to see if people have any suggestions for improvement. I'd say give it some thought. You can always ask there even once you think you have a good idea to double check it.

Comment: It might not be quite the same question, but it may work to ask about specific experiences others have had with phone users of various stripes at their tables, whether or not the phone use affected the games in any way, or something like that. But asking about what people feel or think, particularly about something being acceptable or unacceptable without a specific impact on the game or group to discuss, is generally problematic on SE.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. "What do you think"-type survey questions are inherently opinion-based, as discussed above. I think part of the problem here is that you don't actually seem to have a problem you need help solving; you're just soliciting opinions and observations with no real goal. Thus, I'm not sure we can find a way to edit your question to be "stackable"... It could make a decent discussion in chat, though, or on a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/33569).